# Unity App size doubled when ported from android to IOS/Xcode

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

My app size has more than doubled from 21MB to 44MB when ported over from android to ios and compiled in xcode (default settings with a few imported frameworks for admob and chartboost). Any ideas on why this is and if there is any way to reduce it?

I've gone through my texture/audio settings after converting the project, and all of them seem to be the same, so im not sure on why the sudden increase.

```
EDIT:
a bit more info:
-unity target device (iphone + ipad)
-Target OS - 5.1

Xcode
-architectures - armv7
-Valid architectures - arm64 arm7 arm7s
-base sdk - IOS 8.1
-supported platforms - iphoneos
```

everything else is pretty much default

Answer (score 0):

well. its a very general question but you should know some important things.

first one is when you export your game for a platform the unity add the assembly files and system files and... for that platform. for example if you export and empty project for android you will see its about 9mb. it maybe different for ios for pc and...

second one is how package format of these platforms are compressed. different compression algorithm they use, the different size of final output will be.

there was a same problem for me that i wanted to avoid using data files with my apk file. there is not much problem with more file size untill it doesnt effect you game/program quality.

there is a topic on unity website about this problem.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/233563/transferred-game-from-android-to-ios-why-is-the-fi.html
its may because you made output for both arm6 and 7

Comment: I see. Is it still normal for file size to double. I've checked unity's logs and my total used assets in the app come up to just 9.7MB, counting the additional 9mb that unity takes for itself, the final app size is still 44.9MB for some reason. Is there anything I can change in the default build settings to reduce this?

Comment: check you player settings when you want to export you final file. i found nothing about compression. search in internet for some program that compresses formats you want but dont count on it, most compressions dont reduce some much. check for other unity versions for your export. i found a topic on unity forum that has same problem of you. i edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, just found out that depending on your project, your development build may be significantly larger than your actual release build. Mine was 44.9MB when testing on my iphone, but the actual release build which needed to be submitted to itunes was only 28MB. (Also the estimate button in your archives window may also show higher numbers sometimes, even for your release build)
  From reading, I found out that this could be reduced further, however I decided to stop here and go with this build for now as 28 mb seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that when you just build with Xcode and check the size of the produced .APP, that is not the one will be uploaded to AppStore. This is uncompressed unlike .APK on Android or the .IPA on iOS which is compressed by ZIP actually (just like .JAR).

On my quick test I have compiled a minimal project with only a text label on it and got a 43MB .APP. When I zipped it up manually, I got around 9.2MB .ZIP file, and when I have done an Archive build and exported that to a folder I have got a 7.4MB .IPA file... Obviously when you do an Archive (Final Release) build that is not only a dumb zipping it up process. Xcode will strip off every unnecessary thing from your executable, hence the smaller footprint...

Anyways, I think the file size is acceptable in my opinion.